# Filtering out "other" from a conversion goal

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to make a report in a dashboard of a conversion goal.

Which shows me the name of the day of the week, which contains the hours in which the goal has been completed.

[image: bar chart]

However I would have like to filter out the "Other" because I would only like to see the amount of the completed goal per hour per day.

[image: selections]

Answer (score 2):

First off, my assumption is that your reference to "Other" means "day of the week" as you stated that you would "only like to see the aount of the completed goal per hour per day"

Either way, Let's create a custom report, you can find this on the left sidebar:
[image: custom analytics report]

Next, Click New Custom Report, which should take you to a screen that looks like this:

[image]

Click "Metric Groups" and select the conversion goal that you are interested in measuring.

Lastly, Under "Dimension Drilldowns", Select "Time", and then pick the variable that is relevant to how you are trying to visualize your data. Since I don't completely understand your question, I can't tell you which one to select. However, If you simply wanted to see how many conversions you receive during each hour of the day (for your underlying time period), your report would look like this:

[image]

Let me know if I can provide further clarification!

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted indeed! :) However.. I would like to know I would be able to make this report in my dashboard, I can't choose the dimension hour in a  dashboard widget.

Comment: It should be there. Make sure that you are filtering the correct conversion action.

Comment: @Elvira After following the steps I provided to make your report, save your report - and then 1. go to the report section of your sidebar, 2. open the report, and finally 3. click the link that says "add to dashboard". I believe that this will accomplish what you are trying to do. I suggest giving this approach a try!